# Total co-occurrence counts from a matrix of N clustering experiments over M data points

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a matrix where every row is the output of a clustering algorithm. For instance, with 3 experiments, 7 data points and 4 possible clusters it might be:

```
# 1 2 1 2 2 3 3 # output of first clustering. Numbers are cluster labels
# 1 2 1 2 3 4 4 # output of second clustering
# 2 1 2 3 2 1 1 # output of third clustering
```

I know how to create a co-occurrence matrix that tells whether two points are in the same cluster:

```
xp <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
pairwise <- apply(as.matrix(xp), 1, 
                 function(x) as.numeric(x==as.matrix(xp)))
```

How can I get the sum of the pairwise matrices of all the experiments?

I do this:

```
# toy data
cluster.assignments <- t(replicate(100,sample(10, replace=TRUE)))

n_samples <- dim(cluster.assignments)[1]
n_dim <- dim(cluster.assignments)[2]
pairwise <- matrix(0, n_dim, n_dim)
for(i in 1:n_samples){
    pairwise <- pairwise + 
        apply(t(cluster.assignments[i,]), 2, 
              function(x) as.numeric(x==cluster.assignments[i,]))
}

pairwise
```

But this is a bit too slow when I have 10000 rows. I guess there is a way to do some sort of apply to avoid this `for` but I can't find it.

Comment: `apply(t(cluster.assignments[i, ]), 2,  function(x) as.numeric(x == cluster.assignments[i, ]))` is equivalent to `sapply(cluster.assignments[i, ], "==", cluster.assignments[i, ])` or `outer(cluster.assignments[i, ], cluster.assignments[i, ], "==")` that might be somewhat efficient. Since you are comparing every pair of columns you could treat each column as an element and use something like `do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(ncol(cluster.assignments)), function(j) colSums(cluster.assignments[, j] == cluster.assignments)))` with some tweaks to avoid testing same column pairs for equality twice.